# Which IDE to use for Android Phone development?

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

I see another person asked this question and was answered but the other person was on a Mac. Also, I want to know *why* people are recommending the Classic Eclipse IDE. What is "Java EE"?

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit.

I'm new at using Java but I don't want to start off with something that will later need changing. If I am intending to write apps for Android Phones (and later tablets), which environment should I use?

I see the following options for download:
- Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
- Eclipse Classic 3.6.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

For a list of the different Eclipse editions, see http://eclipse.org/downloads/

"Java EE" is a release of Eclipse with all the features that are particular useful for Java EE development. Other similar editions are aimed at PHP, plug-ins, C++, etc.

Any of these can be used as the basis for Android development, but if you "just" want to development Android stuff and have no need for Java EE support, PHP or whatever, then choose "...for Java Developers", as it is the smallest available...

Answer (score 0):

You can write in Javascript using titanium.It converts the code js to java or objective c.
I think this is the easiest way.It's the titanium [link](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Comment: Can you please tell me why you recommend Titanium? Their web site is mostly to promote them, of course. I'm looking for slightly more objective info. I am wary of an environment being too easy/high level but sacrificing features/flexibility. Don't get me wrong! I would love the highest level as possible!

Comment: YOu are right.I just recommend it because you can learn it easily and start doing things.I think you know Java but still Java and objective c is very hard.I never used titatinium but i watched http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-overview-a-few-moments-with-titanium/ it.Also i looked tutorial like http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-simple-services then i decided that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse download for Java Developers and install Android Development Toolkit (ADT) plugin from Google.

Eclipse Pulsar which is intended for mobile developers is also available for from Eclipse downloads home.

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to using Visual Studio on windows or other big IDEs, I'd recommend you use Eclipse for Java Developers.

If you are just getting started, I'd suggest you skip out on IDEs.  For me, Eclipse was more trouble than I needed.  Using VIM or Notepad++ and a batch file gives you great results.